# insert into a table from another table and add value from variable also in one SQL code

Tags: php, sql

i am using `INSERT INTO SELECT` Statement Syntax to insert values from another table into my main table 
in my php project

```
$student_id=1; // dummy id set in a variable
include 'conndb.php';
$sql = "INSERT INTO `student_resulttbl` ( subject_name,)\n"

        . "SELECT subject,\n"

        . "FROM `subjecttbl`\n"

        . "WHERE  subject_class ='$class' AND subject_session = '2020/2021'";
```

It worked well but my issue is how to insert variable $student_id along with this on student_resulttbl. pls note `$student_id` is not coming from subjecttbl. Its set already. Thank you

Comment: You could use something like `SELECT $student_id, subject,`  BUT you should look into using prepared statements!

Comment: There is no column student_id on subjecttbl

Comment: It isn't a column, it's a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to `INSERT` `$student_id` to `student_resulttbl` table you should do query like this:

```
INSERT INTO `student_resulttbl` ( subject_name, student_id ) VALUES ( 
(    SELECT subject FROM `subjecttbl` 
     WHERE  subject_class ='$class' 
     AND subject_session = '2020/2021'
),
$student_id);
```

The summary code:

```
$student_id=1; // dummy id set in a variable
include 'conndb.php';
$sql = "INSERT INTO `student_resulttbl` ( subject_name, student_id ) VALUES (" 
. "(SELECT subject FROM `subjecttbl` "
. "WHERE  subject_class ='$class' "
. "AND subject_session = '2020/2021'"
. "), $student_id)";
```

You can `INSERT` multiple columns with `INSERT INTO` command. More information there:
w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp
or
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp
or
https://www.dofactory.com/sql/insert

Comment: Would have thought https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp was a more appropriate resource.

Comment: I have never mind, thank you I will add this resource too, Thank you! @NigelRen

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this?

```
$student_id=1; // dummy id set in a variable
include 'conndb.php';
$sql = "INSERT INTO `student_resulttbl` ( student_id, subject_name,)\n"

        . "SELECT " . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $Student_id) . ", subject\n"

        . "FROM `subjecttbl`\n"

        . "WHERE  subject_class ='$class' AND subject_session = '2020/2021'";
```

but have a look at prepared statements.

Is there a reason why you use newlines in SQL-Statements?

Comment: Think you have a misplaced comma in the fields you are selecting